when installing laravel breeze package in laravel 10 getting error why?
Using version ^2.0 for laravel/breeze
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/breeze
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
- laravel/breeze[v2.0.0, ..., v2.0.5] require illuminate/console ^11.0 -> found illuminate/console[v11.0.0, ..., v11.9.1] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- Root composer.json requires laravel/breeze ^2.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/breeze[v2.0.0, ..., v2.0.5].
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require laravel/breeze:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require laravel/breeze:^2.1" if you know which you need.
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
PS C:\Users\jacqu\Ecommerce>
I run this command in terminal
composer require laravel/breeze --dev

which version of composer you are using? In Laravel 10 composer required to be at least 2.0.0 or greater than 2.0.0.This might help you composer require laravel/breeze:*.

Laravel Breeze in v2 is not compatible with Laravel v10, as you can see in the error message. If you want to stick to Laravel v10, use
composer require laravel/breeze:"^1.0"


Sidenote: keep in mind that Laravel v10 will no longer receive usual bugfixes after August 2024. Security support will end in early 2025. Maybe it's better to update Laravel to v11, then you can also use Breeze in v2

only a little optimization note: add --dev to insert package in the 'require-dev' section of your composer.json file

The error message suggests to re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require laravel/breeze:*" to figure out if any version is installable

Running the following command will install the best match for your laravel installation:
composer require laravel/breeze:* --dev

